# difference between switch and switchcompat in android?

Tags: android, uiswitch, switchcompat

Can someone please explain the real difference between `Switch` and `SwitchCompat`.Can I use both as toggle button. can both support lower versions of android. thanks in advance

Comment: @beardedbeast: I think only diff is `Switch` is added from API LEVEL 14 but   `SwitchCompat` is used to support `Switch` control till API LEVEL 7

Comment: ya thats what I saw in the reference

Comment: Then you have your answer.

Comment: is that the only difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As beardedbeast already mentioned in comment, these widgets differ from each other only by the supported API level.
You can use both of them for the same purpose but not simultaneously to avoid unnecessary complication.

As for known issues when using Compat widgets, there is an answer from developers.blogspot:

> You don’t need to do anything special to make these work, just use
>   these controls in your layouts as usual and AppCompat will do the rest
>   (with some caveats; see the
>   [FAQ](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)
>   below).

And one points, which is not mentioned there. To have correct look and behavior of `SwitchCompat` (and other Compat widgets) check if the parent `Activity` (or `LayoutInflater` which you are using to inflate Compat view) is styled with `Theme.AppCompat`.