# Switch vs. SwitchCompat

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library

*A [Switch](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) is a two-state toggle switch widget that can select between two options* and a *[SwitchCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html) is a version of the Switch widget which on devices back to API v7. It does not make any attempt to use the platform provided widget on those devices which it is available normally.*

Given that both are available to any modern Android 4+ app developer, what are the reasons to use one or another? What are the core differences?

Comment: I think only difference is the Api support as mentioned in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604164/difference-between-switch-and-switchcompat-in-android.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

There is a huge difference. `Switch` is platform dependent. It can look differently on different version systems. On post-lollipop devices it inherits from Material Design styles, on pre-lollipop it inherits from holo styles.

`SwitchCompat` inherits from Material Design on every system version.

Of course context `Activity` must be `AppCompat` one.

Using components from support libraries you ensure the same behaviour on all system versions.

[image: SwitchCompat and Switch image on Android 4 and Android 7]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me add a note why that matters: using SwitchCompat I do not have to worry about the "on"/"off" texts on older devices, which make no sense in my "yes"/"no" context.

Comment: Those texts are in resources in appCompat library. So it is translated into all languages in support libraries, which practically means all that android supports.

Comment: But SwitchCompat has no text at all, has it?

Comment: It may have (attribute [`textOn`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html#attr_android:textOn)), you can still customise `SwitchCompat`. By default it does not have.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. I added an overview image supporting your text. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: this whole "Compat" thing is such a joke. What are we going to have after Material style is considered outdated... SwitchCompatNew ?